# Hover over element makes second element appear. How to keep second element visible after hovering off of the first?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a dropdown menu in HTML/CSS by using `<a>` elements. So far, I have managed to get the secondary `<a>` (which when the first `<a>` is not hovered, does not appear/is hidden). This in itself is a huge success for me, but my problem is that when I do not longer hover the first `<a>`, the second one disappears, which makes it impossible to click on the secondary `<a>`.

How do I make it stay for as long as I am hovering the second `<a>`?

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 220);
}
.dropdownbutton {
  display: block;
  width: 236px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #8B6969;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana;
  line-height: 33px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.dropalt1 {
  display: none;
  width: 236px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana;
  line-height: 33px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.dropdownbutton:hover + .dropalt1 {
  display: block;
}
a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

```html
<a class="dropdownbutton" href="#">Click me!</a>
<a class="dropalt1" href="#">Link 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into making use of wrapping elements. For example, when the parent wrapper of (of both elements) is hovered over, you should display the element of interest (which will expand the parent).

And only upon hovering off the parent, will the target item be hidden.

```
.hidden-child {
    display: none;
}

.parent:hover .hidden-child {
    display: block;
}
```

Very [rudimentary example](https://jsfiddle.net/agentfitz/xbeqd634/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this style to force the second anchor to stay visible while it's hovered:

```
.dropalt1:hover {
  display: block;  
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o0yz6drt/)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add `.dropalt1:hover` and make it display block, so that it will stay visible on hover.

Add this to your CSS file:

```
.dropalt1:hover {
    display: block;  
}
```